# Issues centering the most basic CSS drop-down menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, centering

I have a fairly simple CSS drop-down menu that I can't for the life of me figure out how to center on the page without destroying the drop-down effect, which is the result with pretty much everything I attempt. What am I doing wrong?

Code in snippet

```css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,
big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,
dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,
details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;color:black;text-decoration:none;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block;}
body{line-height:1;}ol,ul{list-style:none;}blockquote,q{quotes:none;}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,
q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing: 0;}

#wrap{max-width:1280px;width:100%;margin:auto;}

nav ul li{line-height:44px;float:left;background-color:#64abfb;padding:10px;}
nav ul li a{color:#FFF;padding:10px;font-size:20px;}
nav ul li ul{display:none;}
nav ul li:hover ul{display:list-item;position:absolute;margin-top:5px;margin-left:-10px;}
nav ul li:hover ul li{float:none;}

li a:hover{border-bottom:3px red solid;}
li > a:after{content:' »';}
li > a:only-child:after{content:'';}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the width and the margin to the ul element:

```
#wrap nav ul {
    width: 430px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,
big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,
dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,
details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;color:black;text-decoration:none;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block;}
body{line-height:1;}ol,ul{list-style:none;}blockquote,q{quotes:none;}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,
q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing: 0;}

#wrap{max-width:1280px;width:100%;margin:auto;}

nav ul {width: 430px; margin: auto;}
nav ul li{line-height:44px;float:left;background-color:#64abfb;padding:10px;}
nav ul li a{color:#FFF;padding:10px;font-size:20px;}
nav ul li ul{display:none;}
nav ul li:hover ul{display:list-item;position:absolute;margin-top:5px;margin-left:-10px;}
nav ul li:hover ul li{float:none;}

li a:hover{border-bottom:3px red solid;}
li > a:after{content:' »';}
li > a:only-child:after{content:'';}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note, if you wish to avoid specifying the ul width, you can display it as inline-block and set its parent element's text-align to center.

Snippet 2:

```css
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,
big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,
dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,
details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video
{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;color:black;text-decoration:none;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block;}
body{line-height:1;}ol,ul{list-style:none;}blockquote,q{quotes:none;}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,
q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing: 0;}

#wrap{max-width:1280px;width:100%;margin:auto;}

nav {text-align: center}
nav ul {display: inline-block; margin: auto;}
nav ul li{line-height:44px;float:left;background-color:#64abfb;padding:10px;}
nav ul li a{color:#FFF;padding:10px;font-size:20px;}
nav ul li ul{display:none;}
nav ul li:hover ul{display:list-item;position:absolute;margin-top:5px;margin-left:-10px;}
nav ul li:hover ul li{float:none;}

li a:hover{border-bottom:3px red solid;}
li > a:after{content:' »';}
li > a:only-child:after{content:'';}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```